# Apple pay with magento

Tags: ios, objective-c, magento, soap-client, applepay

I am working on iPhone application that is online store kind of app. We are getting all data using magento built In API.

I want to use `Apple Pay` with my magento application but not sure magento support or not with it's `built in API` or with `extention`.

For `Apple Pay`, I checked with below link but not sure that works with magento or not. [Stripe Apple Pay](https://stripe.com/apple-pay)

Please suggest me can we use apple pay with magento/it's extention from iOS application.

Comment: You will have to create a payment gateway module that will interface with an NFC scanner and Magento.

Comment: you cannot to apple pay on a website, you can only do apple pay within an app.

Comment: @MatthewArkin thanks Yes I don't want to do in web site but when I do in app then want to know how it will interatc to store payment method or token etc. Thanks for the reply

Comment: That all depends on how you build the app, Apple Pay would be something done at the app level assuming your payment processor supports it.